# What is the meaning of questionmark in firebug net tab?

Tags: firebug

Here is the print screen.
I have marked the size column with red rectangular.
[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1117/fbug.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1117/fbug.png)
[Full image link](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1117/fbug.png)

Added link for
[Expanded headers](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/3941/headersg.png)

Comment: Can you expand that line and show us the headers tab for that request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the question mark is displayed in cases where Firebug couldn't figure out
the size of the response (e.g. missing Content-Length header). This is considered rather as a bug and should be fixed in the combo: Firefox 3.6 + Firebug 1.5
Honza

Answer (score 0):

See this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=869).  Problem appears to be the lack of a Content-Length header for those file.

Comment: I've seen it already.It was my first google search, but I don't think it is the same problem. This issue shows only question mark, but I got both size and question mark :(